# Kinect depth conversion from mm to pixels

Tags: kinect, pixel, depth, meter

Does anybody knows how many pixels correspond for each millimeter of depth value in images taken from kinect for xbox360?
I'm using the standard resolution and settings...

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the same question to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784888/kinect-map-x-y-pixel-coordinates-to-real-world-coordinates-using-depth

Comment: Are you using kinect v1 or kinect v2?

Comment: I guess it's v1... It's for xbox 360...

Comment: Not exactly the same... I'll make it easier... In a screen 380mm width with resolution 1920 pixels in X axis, it's 5.05 pixels for each milimeter... in kinect (or general a camera) how can I do the same? I guess it's something like (field of view)/(resolution) and somehow related to the distance from the camera... but I'm not sure and i can not find it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

1 pixel corresponds to a number of millimiters that depends on the depth value of that pixels (i.e. its level of gray).

The simplest way you can get the distance between two pixels in a depth image is to convert those pixels (which are expressed in *Depth Space*) in real world coordinates (i.e. in *Skeleton Space*)<sup>1</sup>. Then, you can calculate the distance between those points using a common [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) formula.

So if you have two pixels P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub>, with depth values 
respectively equal to D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>, you can proceed as follows:

```
DepthImagePoint dip1 = new DepthImagePoint();
dip1.X = P1.x;
dip1.Y = P1.y;
dip1.Depth = D1;
DepthImagePoint dip2 = new DepthImagePoint();
dip2.X = P2.x;
dip2.Y = P2.y;
dip2.Depth = D2;
SkeletonPoint sp1 = CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToSkeletonPoint(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30, dip1);
SkeletonPoint sp2 = CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToSkeletonPoint(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30, dip2);

double dist = euclideanDistance(sp1, sp2);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Coordinate Spaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) for more information.