# converting meter into pixel unit

Tags: kinect, pixel, point-cloud-library, ros

i am trying to convert convert distance from meter to pixel in ros node, with pcl library and kinect xbox. I was using below code to access euclidean coordinates of every point from kinect inside ros node, which is in meter. But i wanted to get this measurments in pixel unit. What should i do?

```
void
cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> output;
 pcl::fromROSMsg(*input,output );
for(int i=0;i<=400;i++)
 {
   for(int j=0;j<=400;j++)
     {
       p[i][j] = output.at(i,j);
       ROS_INFO("\n p.z = %f \t p.x = %f \t p.y = %f",p[i][j].z,p[i][j].x,p[i][j].y);
     }
  }
 sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
 pcl::toROSMsg(output,cloud);
 pub.publish (cloud);
}
```

Here P[raw][col] is a Point structure which contains the x,y,z coordinates value in meter, which i want to convert in pixel unit. As i see the value of pixel unit is not constant, so cant use any value found in google.
I got similar question here: [Kinect depth conversion from mm to pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752364/kinect-depth-conversion-from-mm-to-pixels), but it has no solution.

Comment: Well the x and y data are going to have to be calculated using trigonometry dependent on the z data. Is that what your asking for is the trigonometric methods to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with trying to convert meters to pixels. Pixels aren't a standard unit. The physical size of 1 pixel varies on different devices depending on screen resolution and size of a screen.

If you know the resolution of the screen the conversion is still non-trivial.

```
const int L = 1920; //screen width
const int H = 1280; //screen height

for(int i=0;i<=L;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<=H;j++){
        p[i][j] = output.at(i*400/L,j*400/H);
    }
}
```

Thus for every pixel you'll have a depth value corresponding to the depth value in the map. This will need some `int` conversion and improvement.