# Kinect intrinsic parameters from field of view

Tags: math, geometry, kinect, projection, camera-calibration

Microsoft state that the field of view angles for the Kinect are 43 degrees vertical and 57 horizontal (stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131033.aspx)) . Given these, can we calculate the intrinsic parameters i.e. focal point and centre of projection? I assume centre of projection can be given as (0,0,0)?

Thanks

**EDIT: some more information on what I'm trying to do**

I have a dataset of images recorded with a Kinect, I am trying to convert pixel positions (x_screen,y_screen and z_world (in mm)) to real world coordinates.

If I know the camera is placed at point (x',y',z') in the real world coordinate system, is it sufficient to find the real world coordinates by doing the following:

```
x_world = (x_screen - c_x) * z_world / f_x
y_world = (y_screen - c_y) * z_world / f_y
```

where `c_x = x'` and `c_y = y'` and `f_x, f_y` is the focal length? And also how can I find the focal length given just knowledge of the field of view?

Thanks

Comment: if you still can't find your answer, have you tried posting here? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?category=kinectsdk they usually have some great responses there for kinect issues.

Answer (score 21):

If you equate the world origin (0,0,0) with the camera focus (center of projection as you call it) *and* you assume the camera is pointing along the positive z-axis, then the situation looks like this in the plane x=0:

[image: Diagram of cameral world coordinates]

Here the axes are z (horizontal) and y (vertical).  The subscript `v` is for "viewport" or screen, and `w` is for world.

If I get your meaning correctly, you know `h`, the screen height in pixels.  Also, `zw`, `yv` and `xv`.  You want to know `yw` and `xw`.  Note this calculation has (0,0) in the center of the viewport.  Adjust appropriately for the usual screen coordinate system with (0,0) in the upper left corner.  Apply a little trig:

```
tan(43/2) = (h/2) / f = h / (2f),  so f = h / ( 2 tan(43/2) )
```

and similar triangles

```
yw / zw = yv / f            also              xw / zw = xv / f
```

Solve:

```
yw = zw * yv / f            and                xw = zw * xv / f
```

Note this assumes the "focal length" of the camera is equal in the x-direction.  It doesn't have to be.  For best accuracy in `xw`, you should recalculate with `f = w / 2 tan(57/2)` where `w` is the screen width.  This is because `f` isn't a true focal length.  It's just a constant of conversion.  If the pixels of the camera are square and optics have no aberrations, these two `f` calculations will give the same result.

**NB:** In a deleted (improper) article the OP seemed to say that it isn't zw that's known but the length D of the hypotenuse: origin to (xw,yw,zw). In this case just note `zw = D * f / sqrt(xv² + yv² + f²)` (assuming camera pixels are square; some scaling is necessary if not). They you can proceed as above.

Comment: I see somewhere in OpenNI the focal length is defined as `525.5f` by default, while f = 480 / 2 / tan(43/2.) = 609.3f. why is that?

Comment: @zhangxaochen The stated FOV angles are probably wrong.  See for example http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/ where the vertical FOV is given as 48.6 degrees as retrieved by the SDK for a real device.  This produces a focal length of 530.

Comment: I'm more confused now... the KinectSDK docs says FOV being `57 & 43`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131033.aspx; while your link and another http://www.bryancook.net/2014/02/comparing-kinect-v1-and-v2-depth-data.html saying them being `58.5 & 45.6 / 46.6`, do they mean the official M$ docs are wrong?

Comment: what's more, the KinectSDK docs and http://www.bryancook.net/2014/02/comparing-kinect-v1-and-v2-depth-data.html do NOT tell image and depth FOVs apart, while http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/ does, with color image FOV being `62 x 48.6`, depth FOV being `58.5 x 46.6`. Does this mean the latter article is more accurate (yet actually I see it wrongly said depth resolution as 320x240)?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Our problem is we don't know what the FOV in the Kinect spec is actually measuring. It could be intentionally decreased from the total camera fov because the parallax depth calculation doesn't work around the edges of the camera fov.

Comment: What software did you use to create this graphic?

Comment: @NMunro I think it's just the Word drawing editor, and I grabbed a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot add comment since i have a too low reputation here.
But I remind that the camera angle of the kinect isn't general the same
like in a normal photo camera, due to the video stream format and its sensor chip. Therefore the SDK mentioning 57 degrees and 43 degrees, might refer to different degree resolution for hight and width.

it sends a bitmap of 320x240 pixels and those pixels relate to

```
Horizontal FOV: 58,5° (as distributed over 320 pixels horizontal)
Vertical FOV: 45,6° (as distributed over 240 pixels vertical).
```

Z is known your angle is known, so i supose law of sines can get you proper locations then  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines