# Kinect - Object recognition and calculating 3D coordinates of objects

Tags: opencv, sdk, kinect, kinect-sdk, point-cloud-library

Please, help me to write Kinect program to recognize objects and their 3D coordinates. And measure their distance between each other. Which library to use, technology and etc.?

Comment: Why have you tagged a possible solution in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather vague question but I suggest you read this topic for starters, it's a similar question.

[How to get real world coordinates (x, y, z) from a distinct object using a Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417495/how-to-get-real-world-coordinates-x-y-z-from-a-distinct-object-using-a-kinec)

Also look at OpenCV, it's a library that can work together with Kinect and can process shapes, recognize objects etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend PCL, which can be found at http://pointclouds.org/.

It supports template matching, image smoothing, etc. They also provide multiple tutorials and with a bit of searching, you should be able to find some implementations of a kinect based scanner.